# AVPlayerLooper in SwiftUI doesn't update video

Tags: swift, swiftui, avfoundation

In SwiftUI I implemented AVPlayerLooper.

When the URL changes that is passed to the view, it should "recreate" the player aka loading the new url

The looping works but it doesn't update the video on URL change.
Apparently the UIView url set {} gets called with the correct newValue but for some reason it does not have any effect on the video. Is SwiftUI caching the player or something?

```swift
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

struct PlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {
  var url: URL
  private let player: LoopingPlayerUIView
  
  init(url: URL) {
    self.url = url
    self.player = LoopingPlayerUIView(frame: .zero)
  }
  
  
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {
    self.player.url = url
  }
  
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    return player
  }
}


class LoopingPlayerUIView: UIView {
  
  private var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
  private var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper?
  private var player: AVQueuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer()
  
  var url: URL {
    set {
      self.playerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
      self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
      let asset = AVAsset(url: newValue)
      let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
      
      // Setup the player
      self.player = AVQueuePlayer()
      self.playerLayer.player = self.player
      playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
      layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer)
      
      // layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
      
      // Create a new player looper with the queue player and template item
      self.playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: item)
      
      // Start the movie
       player.play()
    }
    get {
      fatalError()
    }
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
  
  override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)

  }
  
  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    playerLayer.frame = bounds
  }
}
```